# .Net COM object causing Access to crash when firing an event from a new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, ms-access, events

Ok guys, this is a tough one AFAIC...  I have built a COM accessible type library in C# and am trying to expose it to MS Access. I am able to reference, set and read properties and two of my 3 events fire just fine.  The third event however causes Access to crash. I am logging in great detail to the event log everything that is going on within the component as Access sets properties and receives events.

The best that I can tell is that when my event is fired the component is throwing a null ref exception because the event is not being handled... (although I have a handler in the Access app and the other handlers are working fine).

The difference between the handlers that work and the one that does not is that the process that fires the deviant event is running async on another thread.

Basically what the program does is read events from an HID port. The `deviceConnected` and `deviceDisconnected` are raised from the main thread.  The process that reads scanned data is calling an `AsyncCallback as` follows:

```
var v = m_oFile.BeginRead(arrInputReport, 0, m_nInputReportLength, new AsyncCallback(ReadCompleted), arrInputReport);
```

and then `ReadCompleted` fires the initial event which bubbles up to the Access program.

I even tried to use `BeginInvoke` to call the Access event as follows:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    try
    {
        EVLog.Logger.LogInformation("Firing DeviceDataReceived");
        DeviceDataReceived();//***<--this is handled by access and is throwing a null ref exception as if it is not being handled***
        EVLog.Logger.LogInformation("Event fired");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        EVLog.Logger.LogException(ex, "");
    }

}), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

Any clue to the right direction would be most appreciated!

Comment: As a side note, even if there is a problem with Access or the general setup, your class should not fail on no event subscribers.

Comment: Might be of interest: [Threading Support in Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sesy69e.aspx)